# C# Added MySQL Reference Into C# Still Not Recognizing MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

[References](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cU9N3.png)

It is referenced, I have downloaded the connector, yet it refuses to work. I rebuilt and cleaned, doesn't work.

```
The type or namespace name 'MySql' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: Ensure `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` DLL assembly included in `bin` folder. Better to use Package Manager & type `Install-Package MySql.Data`.

Comment: How about adding that from Nuget?

Comment: Check the target framework of the project where are making the reference and check the Runtime Version of the MySql assembly and see what they are.

Comment: have you tried installing mysql for visual studio https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/7e1598350ae3a285c50319198412120a.png  What folders look like. Is this right?